# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81. How to counter this

Tags: python, user-interface

Even by given "encoding = 'utf-8'" or even giving "errors = 'ignore'". I am getting hit with the same error.

```
def open():
    global My_Image
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir = '/Users/GAURAV/Desktop', title = "Select an Image file.", filetypes = (("JPG files", "*.jpg"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    my_label = Label(root, text = root.filename).pack()
    My_Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))          #over here
    My_Image_Label = Label(image = My_Image).pack()
```

Comment: it may means that data is not in `UTF-8` but `latin1`, `cp1250` or other encoding.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: better use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile`  because `askopenfilename`  gives filename and `askopenfile` opens file and give pointer to this file, not its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter` has two functions `askopenfile` (which you use) and `askopenfilename`.

Second function (`askopenfilename`) gives string with filename.

But first function (`askopenfile`) opens file in text mode and it gives access to this open file, not its filename.

If you use `print(type(root.filename))` you will see `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>` instead of `<class 'str'>`

And this makes problem - to read image you need bytes mode, not text mode.

So better use `askopenfilename` to get filename and `Image.open()` will open it in bytes mode and read it correctly.

---

**EDIT:** eventually you can use `mode="rb"` in `askopenfile` to get file opened in bytes mode

```
root.filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(mode='rb', initialdir=..., ...)
```

and `print(typo(root.filename))` will show `<class '_io.BufferedReader'>` and it should also work with `Image.open()`

---

**BTW:** when you use `askopenfile` you get opened file and its name is in `root.filename.name`

Comment: Thanks furas. You've been helpful.